# FIND_IN_SET too slow with GROUP_CONCAT (Dense Rank in MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that calculates dense ranks based on the value of a column :

```
SELECT id,
       score1, 
       FIND_IN_SET
       ( 
         score1, 
          ( 
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(score1  ORDER BY score1  DESC) FROM scores 
          ) 
       ) as rank 
FROM score_news;
```

This is what the query results look like:

```
+----+--------+------+
| id | score1 | rank |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 |     15 |    1 |
|  2 |     15 |    1 |
|  3 |     14 |    3 |
|  4 |     13 |    4 |
+----+--------+------+
```

The query takes Nx longer time when number of scores increases by N times. Is there any way I can optimize this ? My table size in the order of 10<sup>6</sup>

**NOTE:** I have already tried a technique using mysql user variables but I get inconsistent results when I run it on a large set. On investigation I found this in the MySQL docs:

> The order of evaluation for user variables is undefined and may change
>   based on the elements contained within a given query. In SELECT @a, @a
>   := @a+1 ..., you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and
>   then do an assignment second, but changing the query (for example, by
>   adding a GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY clause) may change the order of
>   evaluation...The general rule is never to assign a value to a user
>   variable in one part of a statement and use the same variable in some
>   other part of the same statement. You might get the results you
>   expect, but this is not guaranteed.

My attempt with user variables :

```
SELECT
      a.id,
      @prev := @curr as prev,
      @curr := a.score1 as curr,
      @rank := IF(@rank = 0, @rank + 1, IF(@prev > @curr, @rank+@ties, @rank)) AS rank,
      @ties := IF(@prev = @curr, @ties+1, 1) AS ties
    FROM
      scores a,
      (
        SELECT
          @curr := null,
          @prev := null,
          @rank := 0,
          @ties := 1,
          @total := count(*) 
        FROM scores 
        WHERE score1 is not null 
      ) b
    WHERE
      score1 is not null 
    ORDER BY
      score1 DESC
   )
```

Comment: I'm trying to calculate a dense rank, so two exactly similar scores would get the same rank.

Comment: It does give me dense ranks.

Comment: Editied my question for clarity, please check.

Comment: Which version of mysql are you on? Could you add your attempt with variables as well?

Comment: @trincot I've added my attempt with variables, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution with variables could work, but you need to *first* order the result set, and only *then* work with the variable assignments:

```
SELECT a.id,
       @rank := IF(@curr = a.score1, @rank, @rank + @ties) AS rank,
       @ties := IF(@curr = a.score1, @ties + 1, 1) AS ties,
       @curr := a.score1 AS curr
FROM   (SELECT * FROM scores WHERE score1 is NOT NULL ORDER BY score1 DESC) a,
       (SELECT @curr := null, @rank := 0, @ties := 1) b
```

NB: I placed the `curr` column last in the `select` clause to save one variable.

Comment: Brilliant, this works for me and is superfast, though I will have to check a few more test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following query to get your dense rank without using user defined variables

```
SELECT 
  a.*,
  (SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT score1) 
  FROM
    scores b 
  WHERE a.`score1` < b.score1) + 1 rank 
FROM
  scores a 
ORDER BY score1 DESC
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c58cb/1)

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00aa66/2) using your data set

> An index on score1 column might help you

Comment: If you notice, the row with score 14 gets a rank of 3, and not 2. I'm thinking of how I can modify your query to get a result like that.

Comment: @bitsapien Why you need 3 not 2 ? its the second highest not 3rd right ?

Comment: This rank is used to calculate percentiles, so the above style of calculating ranks won't help.

Comment: @bitsapien something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00aa66/3 ? but these are not proper ranks you can say them as missing ranks

Comment: That worked for me, but it was extermely slow, slower than my original query. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: @bitsapien Even after indexing your score1 column ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159768/discussion-between-bitsapien-and-m-khalid-junaid).